Number of surjective maps from a non-empty finite set to another
A week ago, in our class, we were being taught about functions. During the class, Prof. gave us some formulae to prove using permutations.
Let us consider two non-empty sets $X$ and $Y$ such that $|X|=m$ and $|Y|=n$ $(m,n \in \Bbb{N})$.
We know that one-one mapping from $X$ to $Y$ is possible if and only if $m \leq n$
Using permutations, we can show that no. of possible bijections will be $^nP_m$
Proof:
Let, $X=${$x_1, x_2,....,x_m $} and $Y=${$y_1, y_2,....,y_n $}
Supposse, $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a one-one mapping. Hence, each element in $X$ will have distinct images in $Y$.
Now,
$x_1$ has $n$ possible choices from $Y$ to have an image.
Given, $x_1$ has an image, $x_2$ has $(n-1)$ possible choices from $Y$ to have a distinct image.
Given, $x_1,x_2$ have distinct images, $x_3$ has $(n-2)$ possible choices from $Y$ to have a distinct image.
Continuing the process,
Given, $x_1,x_2,....x_{m-1}$ have distinct images, $x_m$ has $(n-m+1)$ possible choices from $Y$ to have a distinct image.
$\therefore$ No. of possible one-one mappings will be- $n(n-1)(n-2)....(n-m+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}=$ $^nP_m$
We know that bijection from $X$ to $Y$ is posssible if and only if $m=n$
i.e. bijection can be considered as a special case of one-one mapping.
Hence, total no. of possible bijections will be $^nP_n=n!$
I felt curious about what is the condition such that onto mapping is possible and how many can be configured. Prof. suggested me to check for smaller sets and then go step by step. I have figured out that $m\ge n$ because if $m<n$ onto mapping is not possible because $m$ elements of $Y$ can have maximum of $m$ images.
So, I created a table using the data.



Cardinality of $X$
Cardinality of $Y$
No. of possible onto mappings




1
1
1


2
1
1


3
1
1


4
1
1


2
2
2


3
2
6


4
2
14


3
3
6


4
3
36


4
4
24



However, I could not generalize anything out of the data. How can I possibly deduce the result?

As discussed in the duplicate, these are the Sterling Numbers of the Second Kind

(StIrling)${}{}$
